# Push play2 yeoman app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0, yeoman

Trying to push play2-yeoman to heroku. 
As discussed [here](https://github.com/tuplejump/play-yeoman/issues/32) , I did the following

1. heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/47deg/heroku-buildpack-scala.git

I see the following

```
Creating frozen-springs-5883... done, stack is cedar
BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/47deg/heroku-buildpack-scala.git
http://frozen-springs-5883.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:frozen-springs-5883.git
```

I looked at the forked buildpack, it uses a variable called $`{UI_FILES}` , so I added that to heroku config using

```
heroku config:set UI_FILES=ui
```

However when I try to push I get the following error message

```
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 889, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (367/367), done.
Writing objects: 100% (889/889), 1.24 MiB | 2.17 MiB/s, done.
Total 889 (delta 312), reused 845 (delta 294)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done

 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:frozen-springs-5883.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:frozen-springs-5883.git'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Heroku's devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks), you can force heroku to build using the Play 2 buildpack by executing the following command:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git
```

Comment: Hey, firstly thank you. Added more info on the problem. Have you seen this before?